# How to get rid of the escape characters showing in the JSON response?

Tags: java, json, rest, spring-boot

I have a springBoot(version 2.0.0) application which reads a json file from the resource path and a GET method which returns the content of the file.

Following is my json file stored under src/main/resources.

```
{"name":"fileName","fields":[{"fields":{"fieldO":[{"id":"label1","name":"name1"}]}}]}
```

Here is the class which reads the file.

```
@Component
public class ReadFile {

public String read(String path) throws IOException, JSONException {

    String jsonString = null;

    ClassPathResource classPathResource = new ClassPathResource(path);
    try (InputStream inputStream = classPathResource.getInputStream()) {
        // Create the JSON String
        StringBuilder json = new StringBuilder();
        try (Reader reader = new BufferedReader(
                new InputStreamReader(inputStream, Charset.forName(StandardCharsets.UTF_8.name())))) {
            int c = 0;
            while ((c = reader.read()) != -1) {
                json.append((char) c);
            }
            jsonString = json.toString();
            System.out.println(jsonString);

        }
    }
    return jsonString;
  }

}
```

Below is my REST controller.

```
@RestController
public class MyController {

@Autowired
ReadFile readFile;

private static final String PATH = "/myFile.json";
public class FinalValue {
    private Object file;
    private Object data;
    public Object getFile() {
        return file;
    }
    public void setFile(Object file) {
        this.file = file;
    }
    public Object getData() {
        return data;
    }
    public void setData(Object data) {
        this.data = data;
    }   
}

@GetMapping(path = "/file", produces = "application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public ResponseEntity<FinalValue> getFile() throws JSONException, IOException {
    Object obj = readFile.read(PATH);
    if (obj == null) {
        System.out.println("ReadFile is null");
        return new ResponseEntity<>(null, HttpStatus.NOT_FOUND);
    } else {
        FinalValue fv = new FinalValue();
        fv.setData("No User Data");
        fv.setFile(obj);
        return new ResponseEntity<>(fv, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}

}
```

when I try the GET url from postman or from the browser my response looks similar to following:

```
{
"file": "{\"name\":\"fileName\",\"fields\":[{\"fields\":{\"fieldO\":[{\"id\":\"label1\",\"name\":\"name1\"}]}}]}",
"data": "No User Data"
}
```

I am not allowed to change the structure of the json file. How can I process this file to get rid of the escape characters in response?

Comment: Can you change the `private Object file` from being an `Object` to an actual type that models your JSON? You're returning a string so it has to escape all the double quotes inside the string. You'll need to return an actual JSON object if you don't want all the escape characters.

Comment: creating a POJO is not an option at this moment as the `file` is bigger than the sample json I have posted here.

Comment: Can you change all the double quotes to single quotes? Otherwise you need the escape characters since you're returning a string.

Comment: I had to use MapType to solve this issue